# Raspberry Pi C++ PHP Gpio

Tags: php, c++, gpio

I'm quite new at programming and I need some help with an understanding of the following problem.  I have PHP page which controls some C++ functions and These functions control GPIO of RPi.  when I run C++ function everything runs without any problem then I try to run a same C++ function with PHP script it doesn't work.

Thank you a lot for your help and advice
Have a nice Holidays

C++

> ```
> > #include <iostream>
> > #include <wiringPi.h>
> > 
> > int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
> > 
> >  std::cout<< argc+5; // this line returns the value to PHP script 
> >     wiringPiSetupGpio();    pinMode (17, OUTPUT) ;
> > 
> >   for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)   {
> >     digitalWrite (17, HIGH) ; delay (500) ;
> >     digitalWrite (17,  LOW) ; delay (500) ;   } 
> >     return 0;
> ```

PHP

> ```
>    <?php
>
>
>        $foo = True; 
>            if(isset($_GET['on'])){
>               exec('./blink a b c d',$result);
>               echo implode($result);               
>            }
>
>  ?>
> ```

Comment: The output you get would be helpful, does it crash?

Comment: No it doesn't. It works without any problem.

Comment: State of the GPIO doesn't change at all when PHP calls main function. No, it doesn't. It works without any problem. I think problem is in permits

Comment: But what OUTPUT does it give? what does your echo return?